# How do I return the email from the element in webdriver?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I want to scrape the email from this website https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g186389-d14025284-Reviews-The_Queen_s_Head-Dorking_Surrey_England.html

I did this

```
            email = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector(`a[href^='mailto:']`)")
```

and I got back the following

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d4436718129f4ff895594540e491d9f2", element="a5ff3398-f01d-49a5-a61b-04e222fa7f3d")>
```

how do I get the email ?

Answer (score 0):

return the href:

```
return document.querySelector(`a[href^='mailto:']`).href
```